# How to combine `count` and `sum` computations for the same source

Tags: scala, akka-stream

There is a some stream of integers:

`val source = Source(List(1,2,3,4,5))`

Is there possible to get the `(count, sum)` result from the source? For the above example it will be `(5, 15)`.

I guess I should use flows and combine them:

```
val countFlow = Flow[Int].fold(0)((c, _) => c + 1)
val sumFlow = Flow[Int].fold(0)((s, e) => s + e)
```

How to apply the above flows to the source. Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final Total**

The `Flow` that you presented is almost correct for getting a final value after the source is exhausted:

```
case class Data(sum : Int = 0, count : Int = 0)

val updateData : (Data, Int) => Data = 
  (data, i) => Data(data.sum + i, data.count + 1)

val zeroData = Data()

val countAndSum = Flow[Int].fold(zeroData)(updateData)
```

This Flow can then be combined with a `Sink.head` to get the final result:

```
val result : Future[Data] = 
  source
    .via(countAndSum)
    .runWith(Sink[Data].head)
```

**Intermediate Values**

If you want a "running counter", e.g. you want all of the intermediate Data values, then you can use `Flow.scan` instead of fold:

```
val intermediateCountAndSum = 
  Flow[Int].scan(zeroData)(updateData)
```

And you can "drain" these `Data` values into a `Sink.seq`:

```
val intermediateResult : Future[Seq[Data]] = 
  source
    .via(intermediateCountAndSum)
    .runWith(Sink[Data].seq)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val graph = Source.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val fanOut = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
    val merge = builder.add(Zip[Int, Int])

    source ~> fanOut ~> countFlow ~> merge.in0
              fanOut ~> sumFlow ~> merge.in1

    SourceShape(merge.out)
  })


  graph.runWith(Sink.last)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following

```
source.map(list => (list.length, list.reduceLeft(_+_)))
```

I hope its helpful

Comment: This won't work.  the `Source.apply` takes in an Iterable[T] and emits values of type `T`, therefore the the type of `source` is `Source[Int, _]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
case class Stats(sum: Int, count: Int) {
  def add(el: Int): Stats = this.copy(sum = sum += el, count = count +=1)
}

object Stats {
  def empty: Stats = Stats(0, 0)
}

val countFlow = Flow[Status].fold(Stats.empty)((stats, e) => stats add e)
```

Comment: Please explain how this answer solves the question. Raw code does not help the average observer without an explaination.